# disk quota exceeded when trying to deploy Docker container inside LXC

Tags: docker, lxc, container

I have an LXC container running docker. Many containers are running successfully but I am unable to add more; I am trying to deploy a new docker container and getting the following error:

```
container init caused "join session keyring: create session key: disk quote exceeded": unknown
```

But the container has plenty of free space, as does the host. I confirmed this with `df -h` and `df -i` (so, it's not inodes)

What does this error mean and how is it resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the root filesystem that's the issue here, it's the [kernel keyring](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/keyrings.7.html). [This LXC thread](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/error-with-docker-inside-lxc-container/922) explains it well, and has the following solution: on the **LXC host** (not inside the LXC container), raise the maximum number of keys with:

```
echo 5000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/keys/maxkeys
```

`5000` is admittedly arbitrary; select a number that's greater than what you have now.

Quoting Stéphane Graber, maintainer of LXD, [from the thread](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/error-with-docker-inside-lxc-container/922/2):

> Kinda sounds like Docker may be attempting to use the kernel keyring?
> That’d certainly be a new behavior from them…

and credit to simos [also from that thread](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/error-with-docker-inside-lxc-container/922/6) for the provided command, which resolved this for me.

[Further reference on GitHub](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22865)

Answer (score 4):

To add to @Josh's answer. To make this change persist after a reboot you can create a file under `/etc/sysctl.d` with the updated kernel value

```
# /etc/sysctl.d/99-custom.conf
kernel.keys.maxkeys=2000
```

If you are starting a lot of nested containers or unprivileged containers, then you may start to have a lot of processes owned by your mapped user, e.g., UID 1000000.

- The max key limit is per user: [Is kernel.keys.maxkeys per user or per key?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606246/is-kernel-keys-maxkeys-per-user-or-per-key)
- [Setting sysctl variables](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-sysctl-variables/)
- More documentation on what this variable is: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/security/keys/core.html