# Is kernel.keys.maxkeys per user or per key?

Tags: linux-kernel, sysctl

The Linux kernel's documentation on its Key Retention Service states that:

> /proc/sys/kernel/keys/maxkeys /proc/sys/kernel/keys/maxbytes
>
> These files hold the maximum number of keys that each non-root user may have and the maximum total number of bytes of data that each of those users may have stored in their keys.

Though, I find, the wording isn't clear on whether it is per user or per key ´maxbytes´ can be used to store key data. So is it per user or per key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: Per user.

See the demonstration below:

```
┌[rovanion][RiggenBuntu]:~
└$ keyctl add user a-key some-data @u
812046028

┌[root][RiggenBuntu]:/
└# cat /proc/key-users
    0:    95 94/94 83/1000000 1687/25000000
 1000:     5 5/5 5/200 61/20000
┌[root][RiggenBuntu]:/
└# sysctl -w kernel.keys.maxbytes=62
kernel.keys.maxbytes = 62
┌[root][RiggenBuntu]:/
└# cat /proc/key-users
    0:    95 94/94 83/1000000 1687/25000000
 1000:     5 5/5 5/200 61/62

┌[rovanion][RiggenBuntu]:~
└$ keyctl add user b-key more-data @u
add_key: Disk quota exceeded
```