# Error with docker container init caused \"could not create session key

Tags: docker, container

After I installed docker, I grabbed the hello-word image, but I couldn't run the container.

- When I run

  ```
  docker container run -it hello-world
  ```

  I get the following error:

  ```
  docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
          container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused
                   "process_linux.go:402: container init caused
                            \"could not create session key: disk quota exceeded\"": unknown.
  ```
- Inspection of the filesystem yield:

  ```
  # df -i
  Filesystem        Inodes    IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
  /dev/loop2             0        0         0     - /
  none            33004080       46  33004034    1% /dev
  tmpfs           33004080        4  33004076    1% /proc/driver/nvidia
  /dev/sda2       14589952   178201  14411751    2% /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
  udev            32990080      753  32989327    1% /dev/tty
  tmpfs           33004080        2  33004078    1% /dev/lxd
  /dev/sdc1      366247936 19798566 346449370    6% /home/ubuntu/liuyuanlin
  tmpfs           33004080       20  33004060    1% /dev/.lxd-mounts
  tmpfs           33004080    32249  32971831    1% /dev/shm
  tmpfs           33004080      176  33003904    1% /run
  tmpfs           33004080        2  33004078    1% /run/lock
  tmpfs           33004080       18  33004062    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
  tmpfs           33004080       19  33004061    1% /run/user/1000
  ```

I have  made sure my partition is not full. I tried to raise the maximum number of keys. But it shows that I don't have permission to change this file.

```
root@liuyuanlin-container:~# echo 5000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/keys/maxkeys
tee: /proc/sys/kernel/keys/maxkeys: Permission denied 5000
```

I tried to modify the properties of this file, but I also failed.

```
root@liuyuanlin-container:/proc/sys/kernel/keys# sudo chmod 770 maxkeys
chmod: changing permissions of 'maxkeys': Permission denied
```

The properties of the file are as follows
[image]

I tried to modify kernel.keys.maxkeys with the sysctl command, but I still failed.

```
root@liuyuanlin-container:~# sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/99-custom.conf

sysctl: permission denied on key 'kernel.keys.maxkeys'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure your partition is not full with the following commands:

```
df -h
df -i
```

Then, you can try [this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600969/528218):

> raise the maximum number of keys with:
>
> `echo 5000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/keys/maxkeys`
>
> 5000 is admittedly arbitrary; select a number that's greater than what you have now.

**Edit:**

You can also modify the kernel.keys.maxkeys by this way:

1. Edit `/etc/sysctl.d/99-custom.conf`
2. Add `kernel.keys.maxkeys = 5000`
3. Close and save the changes.
4. Type the following command to load sysctl settings: `sysctl -p`

Source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-sysctl-variables/:

Comment: I have used the following two commands to make sure my partition is not full. I tried to raise the maximum number of keys. But it shows that I don't have permission to change this file. `root@liuyuanlin-container:~# echo 5000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/keys/maxkeys tee: /proc/sys/kernel/keys/maxkeys: Permission denied
5000`

Comment: @luye Instead of putting new info in comments, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/739180/edit) your question instead. This way the relevant info is readily available. I added this comment as-is, the edit will be visible when approved by another member of the community; so you can delete this. Please check out Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and review some questions with [accepted answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to learn how the site works.